# Можно ли передать переменные в метод __clone?

Tags: php

Можно небольшой примерчик, как передать переменные?

```
<?php
class SubObject
{
    static $instances = 0;
    public $instance;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->instance = ++self::$instances;
    }

    public function __clone() {
        $this->instance = ++self::$instances;
    }
}

class MyCloneable
{
    public $object1;
    public $object2;

    function __clone()
    {
        // Принудительно копируем this->object, иначе
        // он будет указывать на один и тот же объект.
        $this->object1 = clone $this->object1;
    }
}

$obj = new MyCloneable();

$obj->object1 = new SubObject();
$obj->object2 = new SubObject();

$obj2 = clone $obj;

print("Оригинальный объект:\n");
print_r($obj);

print("Клонированный объект:\n");
print_r($obj2);

?>
```

Хочу при клонировании передавать переменные аналогично как метод __construct.

p.s. с пхп только неделю.

Comment: По моему вы не совсем верно мыслите. Если вам нужен полностью идентичный объект, тогда используйте клонирование, если же нет - инициализируйте новый объект, либо клонируйте и потом видоизменяйте.

Даже если это было бы возможно, это, мягко говоря, не логично.

Comment: Все спасибо за ответЫ.БУДУ учить php.чтобы меньше подобных вопросо было

Answer (score 1, accepted):

...но у нас всегда есть не-тру-ооп методы, типа передачи через суперглобалы `$_SERVER` и  `$_ENV` =)

```
<?
class SubObject
{
    static $instances = 0;
    public $instance;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->instance = ++self::$instances;
    }

    public function __clone() {
        $this->instance = ++self::$instances;
    }
}

class MyCloneable
{
    public $object1;
    public $object2;

    function __clone()
    {
        $this->object1 = clone $this->object1;
        if (!empty($_ENV['some_var'])) {       // !
          $this->someVar = $_ENV['some_var'];  // !
          $_ENV['some_var'] = false;           // !
        }                                      // !
    }
}

$obj = new MyCloneable();

$obj->object1 = new SubObject();
$obj->object2 = new SubObject();

$_ENV['some_var'] = 15;                        // !
$obj2 = clone $obj;

print("Оригинальный объект:\n");
print_r($obj);

print("Клонированный объект:\n");
print_r($obj2);
?>
```

Вывод:

```
Оригинальный объект:

MyCloneable Object
(
    [object1] => SubObject Object
        (
            [instance] => 1
        )

    [object2] => SubObject Object
        (
            [instance] => 2
        )

)
Клонированный объект:
MyCloneable Object
(
    [object1] => SubObject Object
        (
            [instance] => 3
        )

    [object2] => SubObject Object
        (
            [instance] => 2
        )

    [someVar] => 15
)
```

Еще, естественно, можно обертку делать:

```
public function __clone() {
    /* code */
}
public function clone($a, $b) {
    /* code */
  $obj = clone $this;
  $obj->a = $a;
  $obj->b = $b;
  return $obj;
}
/* clone */
$obj2 = $obj1->clone(14,88);
```

Comment: Конечно же можно использовать суперглобалы, в данном случае это будет, скорее, единственным значением - изменение в **MyCloneable::__clone()** некой глобальной переменной вне данной функции , и, возможно даже класса. Но вопрос все же подразумевал прямую передачу аргументов в данный метод класса.

Comment: @Dexter, да, этого сделать нельзя, именно поэтому ответ начинается с "но". В вопросе были вопрос и проблема - на вопрос ответили вы, я решил проблему. Кстати, обертка - более правильный вариант, хак с суперглобалами - это "если ничего другого не остается".

Answer (score 1):

Ну вы бы попробовали для начала это
   сделать сами:

```
   function __clone($pr)
       {
        echo $pr; // тестируем...хотя даже вывод не обязателен...
           $this->object1 = clone $this->object1;
       }
```

**И что же мы видим? Та-да-да-да-да-даааам!**
  **УПС!** Ошибочка, которая гласит, что метод `__clone()` **не принимает
   аргументов**:

```
   Fatal error: Method MyCloneable::__clone() cannot accept any arguments in ...
```

**P.S**  Это и есть умение решать "проблемки" самостоятельно, не ломаясь, выполняя код по увиденному шаблону, если что-то не сходится "тык-в-тык" =)